# Visual Studio always closes Output window when build starts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a weird problem with Visual Studio Premium 2013.  VS has taken to closing the Output window after my build starts.  If the window is unpinned, it briefly opens at the start of the build, and then auto-hides.  If it's pinned, it briefly gets selected, and then moves to another pinned window (it usually opens the Error List window and switches to that).  The one thing it always makes sure of is that it switches away from the Output window.  This is a behaviour that has started recently and I have no idea why - it didn't used to, and I don't remember changing anything related to this behaviour.  Here's my settings, which should cause the Output window to stay open:

[image: Projects and Solutions | General]

I've even tried deleting the solution's `.suo` file, but this problem persists.

Can anyone tell me how to get the Output window to stay open during a build again?

Comment: Actually I wouldn't be surprised if it's something to do with the fact that this solution I'm building automatically builds some `.tt` files - I just tried starting and building a new simple Windows Forms application, and it does indeed open the Output window and keep it open for that solution's build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think this has something to do with the fact that the solution I'm building does a bunch of automated stuff, including the building of some `.tt` files.  It's not a configuration issue in my Visual Studio because the Output window doesn't disappear when I'm building a new simple project I create from scratch, so I guess there's probably nothing I can do to stop the Output window disappearing for this project.